# Is there a way a method can be triggered or run during a salesforce package installation process?

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I would want to do this to run post installation setup process like adding custom data that is required for the application to run.

One option I am aware of is to Write Installation and Setup instructions for users. Create visualforce page and include a button on this page. Redirect user to this page as the process of Installation and ask the user to click the button.

I only wanted to know If there was a more elegant way to solve the problem and if there is a way to call a method during the installation process.

Answer (score 6):

Salesforce has recently implemented the ability to execute scripts (as Apex) during package Install / Uninstall:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_install_handler.htm

Answer (score 1):

No, we can't have a post installation script for the app. What you are saying is best solution, just keep a custom setting to flag, if initial setup is not done, then redirect to the setup page first, other wise do the normal work.

Answer (score 1):

My question would be revolving around why you need custom data for the app to run? One of the things Salesforce look for when doing a security review of your code and the unit tests you have is to check to see if you are requiring data in your org as this is bad practice. Note that if your app is requiring specific data to run then it cannot be tested properly as the data will not be in the org when running the tests on install.

What is the data you are requiring? Could it be stored in an xml like static resource file or something similar for you to load and parse as it is needed?

Paul

Comment: I want to pre-poulate the app with lookup records. These lookUp values will be used while creating other Custom Objects. I anyways would like to create few System defined LookUp records on which The users can build further that is the users will be able to add/delete/modify the LookUp records. The system defined LoopUp records are also going to work as a nice sample data for the users to build further. I can keep the data in a Static resource file(xml), but an object gives me more flexibility. If this is a bad practice, I might need to look at Custom settings to see if that can solve my issue.

Comment: Siddartha, you cannot put data into an installation setup, even in custom settings. You will not be able to do this if you are wanting to release it on the app exchange, only if you will be doing custom installations. Custom settings won't solve your problems I am afraid. When you say lookup records, do you just mean records to be used in lookup fields on other custom objects?

Comment: @pbattison you are correct. I want to use these as lookup fields on other Custom Objects and I also want the Users to be able to decide what the fields should be. More like letting them customize the LookUp values.

Comment: In which case storing it as a csv file as a static resource will be your best option and then having it as a task after installation to upload that into the org. That should be something that is easily within the reach of any administrtor to do.